# C++ calculation of curling number in sequences (Assembly?)

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, sse

I'm writing a program that creates curling sequences -- in short this means that we start with a given sequences, consisting of 2's and 3's (i.e. a mix of 22 of them), and look for repetition at the end of the sequence. The curling number, i.e. *highest frequency of a period at the end of the sequence* is then appended to the sequence and we redo the calculation and append and so on...

Quick example: the curling number (curl) of the sequence **seq = 223223**, **curl(seq) = 2**, because *223* is repeated twice. Then, **seq = 2232232**, and **curl(seq) = 2**, because *232* is repeated twice.

Now, we continue this calculation until we find **curl(seq) = 1**. That's the idea of the program, but then I want to do this for a bazillion amount of sequences (just kidding, more like 2^50).

Thanks to a fellow Stackoverflow user, I switched over to Intel Intrinsics (AVX/AVX2 and SSE) instructions, where we represent a sequence of 2's and 3's with bits in a 256-bit register.

Here's the script -- I tried my best to comment enough, but if there are any questions, be sure to ask them.

```
// the curl of a sequence is defined as : the highest frequency of any period at the end of a sequence
// some examples:
// the curl of 11232323 is 3, because 23 is the most-repeated element at the end of the sequence
// the curl of 2222 is 4, because 2 is the most-repeated element at the end of the sequence
// the curl of 1234 is 1, because every period at the end of the sequence is repeated only once

#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

// Vlad - ShiftRight is my adaptation from http://notabs.org/lfsr/software/
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// bit shift right a 256-bit value using ymm registers
//          __m256i *data - data to shift
//          int count     - number of bits to shift
static void bitShiftRight256ymm(__m256i* data, int count)
{
   __m256i innerCarry = _mm256_slli_epi64(*data, 64 - count);             // carry outs in bit 0 of each qword
   __m256i rotate = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(innerCarry, 0x39);           // rotate ymm left 64 bits
   innerCarry = _mm256_blend_epi32(_mm256_setzero_si256(), rotate, 0x3F); // clear lower qword
   *data = _mm256_srli_epi64(*data, count);                               // shift all qwords right
   *data = _mm256_or_si256(*data, innerCarry);                            // propagate carrys from low qwords
}

// bit shift left by one a 256-bit value using ymm registers
//          __m256i *data - data to shift
static void bitShiftLeftByOne256ymm(__m256i* data)
{
   __m256i innerCarry = _mm256_srli_epi64(*data, 63);                     // carry outs in bit 0 of each qword
   __m256i rotate = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(innerCarry, 0x93);           // rotate ymm left 64 bits
   innerCarry = _mm256_blend_epi32(_mm256_setzero_si256(), rotate, 0xFC); // clear lower qword
   *data = _mm256_slli_epi64(*data, 1);                                   // shift all qwords left
   *data = _mm256_or_si256(*data, innerCarry);                            // propagate carrys from low qwords
}

// mask of 64 to select smaller parts of the sequence
static const uint64_t mask64[65] = { 0,
 0x1, 0x3, 0x7, 0xF, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF,
 0x1FF, 0x3FF, 0x7FF, 0xFFF, 0x1FFF, 0x3FFF, 0x7FFF, 0xFFFF,
 0x1FFFF, 0x3FFFF, 0x7FFFF, 0xFFFFF, 0x1FFFFF, 0x3FFFFF, 0x7FFFFF, 0xFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
};

// mask of 128 to select larger parts of the sequence, built at start
static __m128i mask128[129] = {};
void build_mask()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
       mask128[i] = i < 64 ?
       _mm_set_epi64x(0, mask64[i % 64]) :
       _mm_set_epi64x(mask64[(i - 64) % 64], mask64[64]);

   mask128[128] = _mm_set_epi64x(mask64[64], mask64[64]);
}

// mask a part of the sequence
//          __m256i *m - data to mask
//          int length - length to mask
__m128i masked128(const __m128i* m, int length) {
   return _mm_and_si128(*m, mask128[length]);
}

// check if 2 parts of the sequence are equal
//          __m256i *m - last part of the sequence to compare
//          int length - length to compare
//     __m256i *target - shifted part of the sequence to compare
bool masked128eq(const __m128i* m, int length, const __m128i* target) {
   __m128i masked = _mm_and_si128(*m, mask128[length]);
   __m128i neq = _mm_xor_si128(masked, *target);
   return (_mm_test_all_zeros(neq, neq));    //v0 == v1
}

// find the curling number (curl) of a sequence
//           uint8_t i - current length of the sequence
//   uint8_t last_curl - previous curl in the sequence
//  const __m256i& seq - current sequence
int krul(uint8_t i, uint8_t last_curl, const __m256i& seq) {
   int curl = 1;
   __m128i seq128 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(seq);       // cast the second halve of 256-bit sequence to 128-bit for faster functions
   unsigned char upper_limit = i / (curl + 1);
   for (int j = 1; j <= upper_limit; ++j) {            // since the curl can be 4, we need to start from a fourth of the cached length, up to halve the total length (else curl = 1)
       int freq = 1;                                   // default curl of any length is 1
       __m128i target = masked128(&seq128, j);         // last j bits of sequence
       __m256i temp = seq;                             // copy sequence
       int cond = 2 * j;                               // cond = freq + 1
       while (cond <= i) {                             // while we are within range of the sequence length..
           bitShiftRight256ymm(&temp, j);              // shift the copy of sequence by j bits
           __m128i t128 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(temp);// cast it to length of 128 bits for faster functions
           if (!masked128eq(&t128, j, &target))        // check if the two parts are equal; break if negative, continue if positive
               break;
           if (++freq > curl) {                        // increase freq by one and update curl if the frequency is larger
               curl = freq;
               upper_limit = i / (curl + 1);
               if (curl > last_curl) {
                   return curl;                        // mathematical break: the curl can't be larger than 'last_curl + 1'
               }
           }
           cond += j;                                  // try to find repetition once more
       }
   }  return curl;                                     // return curl (if we didn't break yet)
}

int main() {
   build_mask();

   __m256i seq = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 1200457);  // fill sequence initial sequence
   uint8_t last_curl = 3;                              // if the curl would be > 3, we can break, thus we set the last curl to 3 in advance
   for (int i = 22; i <= 256; ++i) {                   // while within range of the register (256 bits)
       int curl = krul(i, last_curl, seq);             // find curl of the current sequence
       if (curl == 1) {
           std::cout << i;                             // return the current length of the sequence if we encounter 1
           break;
       }
       if (curl > 3) {
           std::cout << i + 1;                         // return the current length of the sequence + 1 if we encounter curl > 3, because the next curl will be 1
           break;
       }
       bitShiftLeftByOne256ymm(&seq);                  // shift the sequence left one bit
       static const __m256i mask1 = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 1);
       if (curl - 2)
           seq = _mm256_or_si256(seq, mask1);          // and add 1 if the curl is 3 (binary twin)

       last_curl = curl;                               // save the curl
   }
}
```

Very quick overview: in main, we start with a specific sequence of length 22 (the binary twin of the 2-3 sequence, represented as an integer). We calculate the curling number by making a copy of the sequence, and shifting it by *j* bits, where *j* represents the length of the period we are testing. we mask these last *j* bits of both sequences, and if they match, this means a frequency of 2 is found, and we repeat this until the shifted sequence and original sequence don't match. We return the highest found frequency after going through all possible options (with a simple mathematical break included). Then, we shift the sequence left by one bit, add the curling number (in its binary twin), and repeat the process, until we find curl(seq) = 1, or curl(seq) > 3, which would result in the next curling number being 1.

The script generates the requested output, i.e. the length of the sequence when the curl = 1 is found. Which, in this case, is 142.

I want to squeeze out more performance, so I wish someone could help me. We would appreciate if someone with knowledge of Assembly could help us, because we would like to know if there are any useless / unnecessary copies from memory to registers. But any other implementation that can be improved by anyone, is welcome anyway!

Thanks in advance!